# How to get window position from top in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Body height is (e.g.) 200%. There is a div. When you click on it, browser should alert, how much did you scroll (like the title says, position from top of document in pixels). I've tried two variants, but none of them works :(

```
var doc = $(document)
var pos = doc.scrollTop();

$(".block").click(function() {
alert('Distance from top is ' + pos + ' pixels')
})
```

If I use `scrollTop`, it alerts "... is 0 pixels", even if I'm at the bottom of the document.

If I use `offset`, it alerts "... is undefined pixels". 
What should I do?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: why do you set `pos` outside of the click handler? You want to get the position at the time of click and not before, don't you? If you think that `pos` will be updated live, you are wrong :-)

Comment: you will have to write it inside the scroll function.. As the var pos  get initialized at the start at it will always be zero

Comment: @devnull69 THANKS!!! I put it inside that click thing and it worked :)

Comment: @user2952227 see this http://jsfiddle.net/HQ3ce/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crossbrowser solution I implemented in a project. Forget where I found it or I'd credit! Probably on another SO question.

```
function getScrollTop(){
    if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
        //most browsers except IE before #9
        return pageYOffset;
    }
    else{
        var B= document.body; //IE 'quirks'
        var D= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
        D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;
        return D.scrollTop;
    }
}
```